# What is the difference between git hooks and Azure DevOps pipelines?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, azure-pipelines, githooks

I am trying to understand git hooks and Azure DevOp pipelines from scratch. I need to understand about the difference between both. Why do we need one over the other? My test environment is Unix and Azure DevOps repository on the server.

Comment: The biggest difference is that they are different things. You cannot compare robots with apples.

Answer (score 0):

Git hooks are designed primarily to run on one machine, either the developer's machine, or in some cases, the remote server. Whether you can use Git hooks on your Git hosting provider depends on the provider. Azure Pipelines is a continuous integration (CI) system which can build, test, and deploy your code.

Git hooks are generally useful if you want to perform some simple operation on a local machine and can generally be easily bypassed, while CI systems are designed to run automatically on many or all commits and potentially across a variety of platforms. CI systems can also securely store secrets that are used to automatically access systems, which you wouldn't want every developer to have access to.

For example, if you wanted to edit a commit message to have a particular format, that's well suited to hooks on the developer's machine. However, if you want to perform automated, consistent testing of all pull requests or automated deployment procedures, that's best suited to a CI system. In general, anything that should be done consistently and repeatably is best left to automation such as a CI system.

Answer (score -1):

In simple terms, `git hooks` are like triggers for a database.  They respond to events that happen within the git source code repository and execute to scripts based on those events.  Like right before checking in code, right after checking in code, etc.  Azure DevOps Pipelines have nothing to do with `git hooks`.  Like what was said:  Apples and Oranges.  I don't know where you got them associated to each other.  Git is a source code repository and Azure DevOps supports Git.  Azure DevOps is a PLATFORM, thus is a combination of many tools under the umbrella of Azure/Azure DevOps.  The "Pipeline" part of it is just a marketing gimmick what we DevOps guys/gals have been doing for years.  It is just a process of taking code from developers and running it through a process of compiling the code, doing some unit testing on it, packaging it, running it through a series of automated tests, evaluating those tests, going through various environments, getting approvals, and eventually in some final environment (usually production).  Since this is usually (but not always) a serial process that sounds like a pipeline (which was introduced in Jenkins/Hudson) and people started calling processes like this Pipelines.  Microsoft just went along with the jargon and went along with the naming convention and added the world PIPELINE to the name.  Now we have Build Pipelines and Release Pipelines that used to be called Build Definitions and Release Definitions (which I still call them that).

Go watch some YouTube videos to help explain this in much greater detail and fill in the gaps.  This is to just point you in the right general direction.